# Get a substring in node js

Tags: node.js, string

I have a mongo connection URL.

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=tst-shard-0
```

I need to pass the db name only which is testDB to resolve. `resolve(client.db(mongoDbName));`

I tried `mongoDbName = mongoURL.split("/").pop().split("?");` and `resolve(client.db(mongoDbName[0]));` but somehow it is failing. It prints correct value of mongoDbName[0] as testDB but still it fails. I guess due to string evaluation.

Any fast and one line approach for this?

Comment: what fails and how it fails?

Comment: It points to client.db and says db is null and fails

Comment: can you add code where you are consuming this resolve

Comment: also add related code for this method you are talking about